# Meteor.js - requiring files

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am struggling to find the Meteor API call analogous to this CommonJS require call:

```
var file = require('file.js');
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

so to my dear Meteor folks: why is this so hard to find? Can someone please point me in the direction of this info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor is a bit different this way. Any file that is a `.js` file is automatically included in the project and concatenated into a big js file.

The way you can picture it is every single js file in your project is just one file.

Variables in other files are enclaved if they are defined using the `var` keyword, and are global if they're defined in the way `foo = "bar"`.

There section at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp explains how the files are loaded & in what order:

For example if you place your files in a folder called `server` then all those will only run on the server.

To do what you're trying to do you can have

file.js

```
Foo = function() {
    return "bar"
}

//usually exports = Foo()
```

Then in your other files, instead of `var Foo = require("file.js"); Foo()`, you can just have `Foo()` *without* the `require` or `exports` stuff.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have a kickOff.js file outside of the client and server folders. I want the kickOff.js file to start the whole application. how do I have kickOff.js talk to the files in the server folder?

Comment: @AlexMills `kickOff.js` already talks to the files in *both* the client and server folders *if* you placed it in the root directory. If you want it to run sooner than the code, that is be higher up in the final js file, put it in a `lib` folder in your projects root directory. This way it runs slightly sooner. If you want it to only talk to the server files, place it in a `lib` directory in the `server` folder (`server/lib`)

Comment: thanks, this really should be more explicit in the meteor docs